# Library/software that could be used to make ecards, overlaying text on images, etc

Tags: linux, image-processing

Is there any open source software or library that could make ecards, or be used to code up something which did this? The one essential feature is that it should allow overlaying text over images and customising the text in images, and making those edited images available for download. (Hence it's not enough to overlay the text on them in HTML, which'd be trivial with JavaScript. It'll require some image manipulation library.)

## My personal requirements

These are my personal preferences, although general answers would also be helpful to readers:

- OS: Should run on a Linux server
- Languages: ideally JavaScript, second choice is Ruby, PHP or Python are also fine.

## Nice-to-have features

These are not core to the question, but since they were requested in comments, here are all the things we'd like the application we build to do: http://pastebin.com/YtQpBQq3

Comment: "software" → should run on which OS? "or library" → for what language? Overall: What features are required/nice-to-have, and are there things you definitely *don't* want? Please [edit] your question and add those (and maybe other) details. The more precise your question, the better fit the answers ;)

Comment: Thanks, added. Is the etiquette/norm around here to ask for your specific requirements, or to ask a more general question which allows answers that could help people using other OSes or libraries?

Comment: Thanks. Just the pastebin is suboptimal. I cannot check what's behind it (blocked by corporate firewall) – but if it's not too long, you'd better include it with your post.

Comment: @tog22 Yes, specific requirements are encouraged to avoid answers that wouldn't run on your system or doesn't fit your budget for example. Here is a post on [what is required for a question to contain “enough information”](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/6834)